# Assign maximum count company to each company and domain in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

[image]I am trying to achieve output in the image.

I could get Company, Domain and Domain_count, not sure how to add the last column that displays the name of the company with maximum domain count

So far:

```
SELECT company, 
       RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) as Domain, 
       count(RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))) as Count_of_Domain 
  FROM table 
 where company <> '' 
   and email <> '' 
   and company <> 'NULL' 
 group 
    by company, 
       RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))
```

Comment: I am trying to do the following:

Company  Domain  Domain_count Company_with_max_domain_count
A             abc.com     8                          E
B             abc.com     6                          E
C            abc.com      4                          E
D            abc.com      3                          E
E            abc.com     12                         E

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table(s) structure(s), some sample data and the result you're trying to get for this sample.

Comment: I am trying to achieve this result:

Company Domain Count_of_Domain Company_with_max_domain_count
A abc.com 4 E
B abc.com 6 E
C abc.com 8 E
D abc.com 10 E
D abc.com 12 E

Comment: I could get first 3 columns using:

 SELECT company, RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email)) as Domain, count(RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))) as Count_of_Domain
         FROM table
         
       where company <> '' and email <> '' and company <> 'NULL'

       group by company, RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))

Comment: This is a really good resource for improving SQL questions: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I guarantee if you follow that guideline, at least with the points Mureinik made, you'll get more quick and accurate answers.

Comment: **Edit** your question, so as to have all information needed there. Don't hide it in comments.

Comment: Something to consider based on your data and query: If a company has multiple domains (e.g. Company F is `companyf.com` and `companyf.org`), that company's totals will be split between those 2 different domains. Not sure if that's an issue for you. But if Company F has 8 `.com` comains and 8 `.org` domains, would you expect it to be considered the company with the most domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would write this using window functions:

```
select company, domain, count_of_domain,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then company end) over (partition by domain) as company_with_max_domain
from (select t.company, v.Domain, count(*) as Count_of_Domain,
             row_number() over (partition by v.domain order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from table t cross apply
           (values (RIGHT(email, LEN(email) - CHARINDEX('@', email))) ) v(domain)
      where t.company <> '' and t.email <> '' and t.company <> 'NULL' 
      group by t.company, v.domain
     ) cd
```

Comment: its giving me error:
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'domain'.

Comment: This is working perfect. I was getting the domain error earlier because in the script you wrote t.domain in the 4th line and it needed to be referred to as v.domain. But it works fine now and query executed in a few secs. Thanks a ton for your help Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery, in which you select only the top row ordered by the count descending. You won't have to repeat that much, if you also use a CTE.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT company, 
       right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email)) as domain, 
       count(right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email))) as count_of_domain 
       FROM table 
       WHERE company <> '' 
             AND email <> '' 
             AND company <> 'NULL' 
       GROUP company, 
             right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email))
)
SELECT company,
       domain,
       count_of_domain,
       (SELECT TOP 1
               company
               FROM cte
               ORDER BY count_of_domain DESC) company_with_max_domain_count
       FROM cte;
```

---

Edit: Above the original question is answered.

If you want to only display the top company of a domain not the top company over all, filter for the domain in the subquery.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT company, 
       right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email)) as domain, 
       count(right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email))) as count_of_domain 
       FROM table 
       WHERE company <> '' 
             AND email <> '' 
             AND company <> 'NULL' 
       GROUP company, 
             right(email, len(email) - charindex('@', email))
)
SELECT c1.company,
       c1.domain,
       c1.count_of_domain,
       (SELECT TOP 1
               c2.company
               FROM cte c2
               WHERE c2.domain = c1.domain
               ORDER BY c2.count_of_domain DESC) company_with_max_domain_count
       FROM cte c1;
```

Comment: This query is not working for me, I am getting same company name through out the records in the column 'company_with_max_domain_count'.

Comment: @Mili: Which is what you have in the image you wrote "I am trying to achieve output in the image." below... So in that regard my query seems to perfectly work for you.

Comment: This query works for one domain, but I have multiple domains, the 'top 1' part of the query assigns the company name with greatest domain count to each domain. I want the company with max domain count within each domain. I will edit the image if its unclear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Mili: See my edit.

Comment: trying this out. I have very large data and hence the query has been running for 22 mins now.